# How can I have a Django application on my main domain, and a PHP application on a subdomain?

Tags: php, django, apache, .htaccess

I have a Django application hosted on my main domain (*example.com*), and I now need to host a PHP application on a subdomain (*forum.example.com*).

In the directory of the main domain, I have the following `.htaccess` entries:

```
SetHandler mod_python
PythonPath "/home/.../apps/example'] + sys.path"
PythonOption mod_python.importer.path "['/home/vlive/python']+ sys.path"
PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython

#PythonDebug On
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.settings
SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp/egg-cache
```

At present, when I load the subdomain (*forum.example.com*) I still see the main site (*example.com*).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Either I'm too sleepy or your english is really-really bad. I cannot understand your problem clearly. Consider reviewing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your subdomains via the `VirtualHost` directive and only add the `mod_python` / `mod_wsgi` handler in one of the `VirtualHost`s.

You said you loaded the subdomain and it still shows the main site. Would you mind showing us your Apache's site configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for wrong VirtualHost being selected is a missing NameVirtualHost directive that matches host/port qualifier specified in VirtualHost directive.

What NameVirtualHost directive do you have set? What is the argument to the two VirtualHost configurations?

The general layout would be:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName forum.example.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

These would usually be in the same file for a Linux Apache distribution though.

What have you used?

Answer (score 0):

As Graham noted, most probably you have wrong VirtualHost configuration.

Double check that there is two different VH with right ServerName and that you don't use * (wildcard) in ServerName and ServerAlias that may overlap with subdomain or it goes AFTER subdomain.
Apache only search for first VH that matches, so if you have something like *.example.com above any other subdomain like forum.example.com would not work.

Also mod_wsgi is recommended by django documentation, consider switching to it.